# SQL Server always on - Indexes on secondary

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

We have SQL Server 2016 installed with Always ON enabled.

Let's say for simplicity, we have one primary and one secondary. I want users to connect to the secondary only with read only access not the primary. In the primary,  I run daily ETL jobs. In order for ETL jobs to run faster, I remove indexes at primary. Now, for the query performances I want to add Indexes on Secondary but not at the primary.

Is that possible in SQL Server 2016 Always ON, without breaking anything?

Answer (score 4):

The always on secondary DB is a full on READ ONLY replica of the primary DB.

So NO, you cannot have different indexes on the replica.

Adding an index will fundamentally alter the pages of a table making replication impossible.

As per Microsoft @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups

> **Indexing**
>
> To optimize read-only workloads on the readable secondary replicas,
>   you may want to create indexes on the tables in the secondary
>   databases. Because you cannot make schema or data changes on the
>   secondary databases, create indexes in the primary databases and allow
>   the changes to transfer to the secondary database through the redo
>   process.

Comment: Is this still the case with SQL server 2019?

Comment: @variable  The page I linked to states that this rule is still in place for SQL Server 2019.